# UNUserNotificationCenter didReceive not being called

Tags: ios, swift

When I send a push notification, and the app is in the foreground `willPresent` is called. `didReceive` is never called. When the application is in the background, and a push notification is received, the alert is shown, but the application never calls `didReceive`, or `willPresent`.

In Project > Capabilities, I have Background Modes `Location updates`, and `Remote notifications` checked. Location updates is for unrelated code.

I have also enabled push notifications. This is working fine, as they are being received.

I have implemented the `UNUserNotificationCenter` notification stuff in my `AppDelegate`, see below:

```
import UserNotifications
...

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
...

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        ...
        registerForPushNotifications(application: application)
        ...
    }

    // MARK: - Push Notifications

    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.delegate = self
        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
            if (granted)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
            else{
                //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
                print("Unsuccessful in registering for push notifications")
            }
        })
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        //convert the deviceToken to a string
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [$0]) }.joined()

        let ud = UserDefaults.standard
        ud.set(deviceTokenString, forKey: "deviceToken")
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        //Handle the notification
        print("User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        //handle the notification
        print("Push notification: ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)

        ... code to import the notification data into Core Data.

        completionHandler()
    }

...
}
```

Any ideas why `didReceive` is not being called?

This is the received push notification:

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "[name] has added you as a friend.";
    category = "NEWS_CATEGORY";
    "related_user_id" = 55;
    sound = default;
    type = "friend_request";
}]
```

iOS 10.1, Swift 3.

Comment: are you testing in bellow ios 10.0?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya no, ios 10.1

Comment: This is only called when user taps on the notification banner, and that the app has been granted notification permission

Answer (score 19):

I found that I need to set the delegate after I get the permission granted.

Otherwise when you launch the app first time ever you register the delegate before you get the permissions and the didReceive function is not triggered - this happened only on the first time you run app, after kill and relaunch it was called just fine.

See below:

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            // Register after we get the permissions.
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }
    })
```

Comment: Bravo! This was far from obvious.

Comment: This might also be an indication that some other code might be setting itself as the `UNUserNotificationCenter` delegate.

Comment: If I could upvote this a million times I would. You have saved me from loosing the millionth grey hair. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

**didReceive** is not executed when you receive a notification, it's executed when the user performs an action on the received notification

From the Apple documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate

> Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.

Meaning this method will be called when the user performs an action on the received notification (push the notification, swipe down, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer to my confusion

Comment: Is there any delegate to execute some task when u receive notification, not when tapped.

Answer (score -1):

The `willPresent` method will be called if you tap on the notification banner.

If you wish to handle the push notifications in the background without having to tap on the banner, then you should append {"content-available":1} to your notification payload. This type of push notification is referred to as *silent* push. This will **not** create a notification banner/alert like a normal push, and you will have to create the banner yourself.

When you receive a push notification with "content-available", the `didReceive` delegate method will be called when the app is in the background.

N.B. You will also have to add 'remote-notification' in the `UIBackgroundModes` key in your plist file.

Comment: I don't think some of the information in this answer is correct. "willPresent" is called if the notification is received while the app is in the foreground (no user interaction necessary). Also, adding {"content-available": 1} does not necessarily mean there will not be a banner - that is dependent on whether there is an "alert" field. Apple docs are not clear about using them together - I've seen it work. "didReceive" of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate is called when the user taps on a banner.